# Add class to the items in wp_list_pages

Tags: wp-list-pages, child-pages, post-class

I just want to add a class for the active page  in the wp_list_pages().Is it possible?
If so  can I provide a particular class for a active page.
Here is my code for listing the parent page and its sub page.

```
       <?php



$output = wp_list_pages('echo=0&depth=1&title_li= &sort_column=menu_order' );
if (is_page( )) {
  $page = $post->ID;
  if ($post->post_parent) {
    $page = $post->post_parent;
  }

  $children=wp_list_pages( 'echo=0&depth=1&child_of=' . $page . '&title_li=&sort_column=menu_order' );
  if ($children) {
    $output = wp_list_pages ('echo=0&depth=1&child_of=' . $page . '&title_li= &sort_column=menu_order');
  }
}
?>
 <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>" class="active">Home</a></li>
<?php 
echo $output;


              ?>
```

Please help me.I want add the class name "active" to the active page in the wp_list_pages(). 
For example I want to display my WP pages as follows.If 1 select the sub page 3 I want to add the class active only to that particular page

```
<div class="page-menu">
                <ul>                    
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="" class="active">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="3" title="">5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code. The Q/A in here is a reference for later users who face the same problem as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved..

I just add the css like as follows and it solve the my problem.

```
.page-menu ul li.current_page_item a{
    background-color:#445C1C;
    }
```

For adding the class for parent page I have used the following code

```
 <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>" <?php if(is_page($post->post_parent )) {?> class="active" <?php }?>>Home</a></li>
```

Hope this may help somebody in future who is facing the same problem, that I have faced :)

Answer (score 1):

As [`wp_list_pages()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.6/wp-includes/post-template.php#L821) has an argument of `walker`, you can use that to replace what is being used by [`walk_page_tree()`](http://queryposts.com/function/walk_page_tree/) as walker class internally.

@Brady has left a nice [example in this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27896/bar-separated-navigation-by-extending-walker-page).

```
class WPSE113482PageWalker extends Walker_Page
{
    function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page )
    {
        // Build $output here and apply your class for the active item
    }
}
```

You might also want to consider using [`wp_page_menu()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_page_menu/).