# Active class on side menu

Tags: sub-menu

Does anyone know how to add an active class onto the side navigation page you are currently on?

The code below works fine but doesnt add an active class

```
<ul class="side-nav">
    <?php global $post;
    $current_page_parent = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );

    wp_list_pages( array(
         'title_li' => '',
         'child_of' => $current_page_parent,
         'depth' => '1' ));
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add class to the items in wp\_list\_pages](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113482/add-class-to-the-items-in-wp-list-pages)

Comment: Well even using the code on that link doesn't output any classes on the li

Comment: `wp_list_pages()` should add a class to the containing list item, so on the current page it will say something like `<li class="current_page_item">...</li>` so you can style it like `li.current_page_item a`

Comment: Nope no classes are being spat out, wonder if its to do with using a custom nav?